# Hyperledger Fabric - Orderer logs show error during broadcast even though the transaction is successful and committed to all peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Orderer logs show following error(highlighted) during broadcast even though the transaction is successful and committed to all peers:

```
2018-12-19 13:43:42.724 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 997 == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2018-12-19 13:43:42.724 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 998 [channel: mychannel] Broadcast has successfully enqueued message of type ENDORSER_TRANSACTION from 172.19.0.7:40978
2018-12-19 13:43:42.724 UTC [orderer/common/blockcutter] Ordered -> DEBU 999 Enqueuing message into batch
2018-12-19 13:43:42.724 UTC [orderer/consensus/solo] main -> DEBU 99a Just began 2s batch timer
2018-12-19 13:43:42.730 UTC [grpc] infof -> DEBU 99b transport: loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"
```

> 2018-12-19 13:43:42.730 UTC [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN
>   99c Error reading from 172.19.0.7:40978: rpc error: code = Canceled
>   desc = context canceled

```
2018-12-19 13:43:42.731 UTC [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 99d Closing Broadcast stream
2018-12-19 13:43:44.724 UTC [orderer/consensus/solo] main -> DEBU 99e Batch timer expired, creating block
2018-12-19 13:43:44.724 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 99f Obtaining default signing identity
```

Fabric Config: All configs and setup same as specified in **Build you First Network** tutorial at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html

**Query**

What is meant by this error? What does orderer read from cli(IP of cli: 172.19.0.7:40978) during broadcast?

Comment: How do you know that the transaction is being successfully committed on all the peers - i.e., how have you checked it? Try submitting new transactions and check if they are being committed by querying peer's local ledger.

Comment: I checked it by querying peer's local ledger.

Comment: yes, that's what. You need to submit new transactions and see if they are going through. Orderers provide two services, broadcast rpc and deliver rpc. Your deliver rpc is working that is why the tx are getting committed at the peers, however, broadcast isn't...hence, try submitting new tx and see what are the errors recorded in both orderer and peer logs.